# Why the text becomes inaccessible when the screen orientation change?

Tags: android, android-layout

1. Started typing (picture A).
2. Rotate screen and continue entering text (picture B).
3. Rotate  the screen in portrait and I see the old text.!

Why?

```
<activity 
 android:name=".activity.Login"
 android:configChanges="orientation"  />
```

onConfigurationChanged:

```
    String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etEmail.setText(email);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    etPassword.setText(password);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogIn);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(lBtnLogin);
```

A:

[image: A]

B:

[image: B]

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

I think after Android 4 this needs to be added as well as screenSize

Comment: If all you want to do is keep the text, you don't need any code in onConfigurationChanged at all

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.

```
String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
etEmail.setText(email);    
etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
etPassword.setText(password);
btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogIn);
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(lBtnLogin);
```

I dont know why do you want to add this code in onConfigurationChanged. It will give the same result without adding this code in onConfigurationChanged.
If you want to set different layouts for different orientation, make one more xml layout and keep it in res/layout-land.